# How can I add an image with coordinates in the UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

Is it possible to add an image in the UIView with specific coordinates?
If so, anyone who is keen on explaining how to?

Comment: You should properly Google around before asking such questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an UIImageView and set it's frame to the desired coordinate.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<#imageName#>]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(<#x#>, <#y#>, <#width#>, <#height#>);
  [yourViewController.view addSubView:imageView];
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmm if says "infoViewController may not respond to -addSubView:" :(

Comment: You need to write `[infoViewController.view addSubview:imageView]`.

Comment: i want to display image with 4 co ordinate means left side height and right side height are different. then how to chnage this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someImage];
myImage.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, myImage.frame.size.width, myImage.frame.size.height);
[myView addSubview:myImage];
```

That'll add an image, contained in an image view, at specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have either to draw the image in `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect;`, by subclassing `UIView`, or to add an `UIImageView` as a subview of the main view, displaying the image.

Have a look on these :

[UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)